# Write array of floats to a wav audio file in swift

Tags: ios, swift, audio, core-audio, audiotoolbox

I have this flow now: i record audio with AudioEngine, send it to an audio processing library and get an audio buffer back, then i have a strong will to write it to a wav file but i'm totally confused how to do that in swift.

I've tried this snippet from another stackoverflow answer but it writes an empty and corrupted file.( [load a pcm into a AVAudioPCMBuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41132418/load-a-pcm-into-a-avaudiopcmbuffer) )

```
//get data from library

var len : CLong = 0
let res: UnsafePointer<Double> = getData(CLong(), &len )
let bufferPointer: UnsafeBufferPointer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: res, count: len)

//tranform it to Data

let arrayDouble = Array(bufferPointer)
let arrayFloats = arrayDouble.map{Float($0)}
let data = try Data(buffer: bufferPointer)

//attempt to write in file
    do {
        let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 16000, channels: 2, interleaved: false)

        var buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(data.count))
        buffer.floatChannelData!.pointee.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: data.count) {
            let stream = OutputStream(toBuffer: $0, capacity: data.count)
            stream.open()
            _ = data.withUnsafeBytes {
                stream.write($0, maxLength: data.count)
            }
            stream.close()
        }
        //settings are from AudioEngine.inputNode!.inputFormat(forBus: 0).settings

        var audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: url, settings: settings)
        try audioFile.write(from: buffer)

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("ERROR HERE", error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

So, i guess i do this transform of floatChannelData wrong or everything wrong. Any suggestions or pointers where to read about it would be great!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With a great colleague help we've managed to get it to work. Apparently, AudioPCMBuffer after filling also needs to be notified about it's new size. 
Also i was using totally wrong formats.

Here is the code:

```
let SAMPLE_RATE =  Float64(16000.0)

let outputFormatSettings = [
    AVFormatIDKey:kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
    AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey:32,
    AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: true,
    //  AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey: false,
    AVSampleRateKey: SAMPLE_RATE,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1
    ] as [String : Any]

let audioFile = try? AVAudioFile(forWriting: url, settings: outputFormatSettings, commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatFloat32, interleaved: true)

let bufferFormat = AVAudioFormat(settings: outputFormatSettings)

let outputBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: bufferFormat, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(buff.count))

// i had my samples in doubles, so convert then write

for i in 0..<buff.count {
    outputBuffer.floatChannelData!.pointee[i] = Float( buff[i] )
}
outputBuffer.frameLength = AVAudioFrameCount( buff.count )

do{
    try audioFile?.write(from: outputBuffer)

} catch let error as NSError {
    print("error:", error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: hi zo_chu i am wondering if the conversion to wav file is done while recording... currently i can record to m4a format then after i stop the recorder will convert the file to wav format. im looking for directly recording in wav format thanks

Comment: @ChinchanZu Hi, well i write directly into wav and it works like a charm. Url in the example leads to a wav file.

Comment: @zo_chu will you please let me know what is buff array in your code ?

Comment: @MaheshDangar in my code buff is an array of Doubles that the library i'm working with is giving me.

Comment: @zo_chu thank you so much for responsing and may i know which liberary have you used ?

Comment: @MaheshDangar that's our own library which other dev team is developing

Comment: @zo_chu okay and thank you very much for responding :)

Answer (score 3):

> Update for Swift 5

This is an update for writing array of floats to a wav audio file in swift 5. The function can be used as the following `saveWav([channel1, channel2])`

```swift
func saveWav(_ buf: [[Float]]) {
    if let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: 44100, channels: 2, interleaved: false) {
        let pcmBuf = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(buf[0].count))
        memcpy(pcmBuf?.floatChannelData?[0], buf[0], 4 * buf[0].count)
        memcpy(pcmBuf?.floatChannelData?[1], buf[1], 4 * buf[1].count)
        pcmBuf?.frameLength = UInt32(buf[0].count)

        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        do {
            let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
            try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: documentDirectory.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("out.wav")
            print(fileURL.path)
            let audioFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: fileURL, settings: format.settings)
            try audioFile.write(from: pcmBuf!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

To make sure the above function works properly, use the following function that converts an audio file to an array of floats, and save it back to an audio file with `saveWav`

```swift
do {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "audio_example", withExtension: "wav") else { return }
    let file = try AVAudioFile(forReading: url)
    if let format = AVAudioFormat(commonFormat: .pcmFormatFloat32, sampleRate: file.fileFormat.sampleRate, channels: file.fileFormat.channelCount, interleaved: false), let buf = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: format, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(file.length)) {

        try file.read(into: buf)
        guard let floatChannelData = buf.floatChannelData else { return }
        let frameLength = Int(buf.frameLength)
        // we convert audio using audio pcm buffer to arrays of floats with two channels
        let channel1 = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start:floatChannelData[0], count:frameLength))
        let channel2 = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start:floatChannelData[1], count:frameLength))
        // we save the audio back using saveWave function
        saveWav([channel1,channel2])
    }
} catch {
    print("Audio Error: \(error)")
}
```