# Play int16 pyaudio bytearray from UDP socket in AVAudioPlayer, iOS

Tags: python, swift, avaudioplayer, pyaudio, pcm

I have a socket server that sends microphone data over UDP using PyAudio. Code looks something like this:

```
stream = pa.open(
    format=pyaudio.paInt16,
    channels=1,
    rate=44100,
    output=False,
    input=True,
    input_device_index=0,
    frames_per_buffer=4096,
    stream_callback=callback
)

def callback(in_data, frame_count, time_info, status):
    server_socket.sendto(in_data, udp_client)
```

Using Python, it's easy to make client that plays audio in real time:

```
stream = pa.open(
    format=pyaudio.paInt16,
    channels=1,
    rate=44100,
    frames_per_buffer=chunk,
    output=True,
    input=False
)

d = client_socket.recvfrom(chunk)
stream.write(d, chunk)
```

Even handling this bytearray in Python is extremely easy, with this oneline:

```
np.frombuffer(in_data, dtype=np.int16)
```

Yet I have no idea how to handle this streaming in Swift 5. 
Now, I tried to do the same in Swift. It looks something like this:

```
var stream_buffer = NSMutableData()
self.connection?.receiveMessage { (data, context, isComplete, error) in
    self.stream_buffer.append(data!)
}
```

And once stream_buffer has acquired enough data...

```
let format = AVAudioFormat(
    commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatInt16,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    channels: 1,
    interleaved: true
)
let buffer_data = stream_buffer as Data
let buffer = buffer_data.toPCMBuffer(format: format!)
```

toPCMBuffer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306996/playing-wav-data-with-avaudioengine)

Yet, I have no idea if I'm doing bytearray conversion correct, or whether AVPlayer even supports Int16 bytearrays. If not, how would I convert my `stream_buffer` to Float32? Has anyone successfully streamed PCM audio to iOS?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but iOS does not seem to work with `pcmFormatInt16`. Instead you are left with two choices: converted the bytearray on the server to float32, and set format to `AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatFloat32`, or convert it on your iOS device. The latter is of course reduced network activity:

convert PCM16 to PCM32, Swift

```swift
let fromFormat = AVAudioFormat(
    commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatInt16,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    channels: 1,
    interleaved: true
)
let toFormat = AVAudioFormat(
    commonFormat: AVAudioCommonFormat.pcmFormatFloat32,
    sampleRate: 44100,
    channels: 1,
    interleaved: true
)

...


let buffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: toFormat!, frameCapacity: AVAudioFrameCount(44100))

let inputBlock : AVAudioConverterInputBlock = { (inNumPackets, outStatus) -> AVAudioBuffer? in
    outStatus.pointee = AVAudioConverterInputStatus.haveData
    let audioBuffer: AVAudioBuffer = (self.stream_buffer as Data).toPCMBuffer(format: self.fromFormat!)!
    return audioBuffer
}
var error : NSError?
self.converter?.convert(to: buffer!, error: &error, withInputFrom: inputBlock)
```

convert PCM16 to PCM32, Python

```py
def int16_to_float32(y):
    """Convert int16 numpy array of audio samples to float32."""
    return y.astype(np.float32) / np.iinfo(np.int16).max

audio_data = np.frombuffer(in_data, dtype=np.int16)
audio_data = int16_to_float32(audio_data)
udp_server.send_data(audio_data.data)
```